# What's the difference between scikit-learn and tensorflow? Is it possible to use them together?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I cannot get a satisfying answer to this question. As I understand it, TensorFlow is a library for numerical computations, often used in deep learning applications, and Scikit-learn is a framework for general machine learning.

But what is the exact difference between them, what is the purpose and function of TensorFlow? Can I use them together, and does it make any sense?

Answer (score 16):

The Tensorflow is a library for constructing Neural Networks. The scikit-learn contains ready to use algorithms. The TF can work with a variety of data types: tabular, text, images, audio. The scikit-learn is intended to work with tabular data.

Yes, you can use both packages. But if you need only classic Multi-Layer implementation then the `MLPClassifier` and `MLPRegressor` available in scikit-learn is a very good choice. I have run a comparison of MLP implemented in TF vs Scikit-learn and there weren't significant differences and scikit-learn MLP works about 2 times faster than TF on CPU. You can read the details of the comparison in [my blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/tensorflow-vs-scikit-learn/).

Below the scatter plots of performance comparison:

[image: Tensorflow vs Scikit-learn on classification task]

[image: Tensorflow vs Scikit-learn on regression task]

Answer (score 3):

Both are 3rd party machine learning modules, and both are good at it.
Tensorflow is the more popular of the two.

Tensorflow is typically used more in Deep Learning and Neural Networks.

SciKit learn is more general Machine Learning.

And although I don't think I've come across anyone using both simultaneously, no one is saying you can't.

Comment: "....Tensorflow is the more popular of the two...." reference?

Answer (score 2):

Scikit learn or more generally if you use in code as sklearn is a machine learning library that comes with out of the box models. You can use these models in your projects if you know how to use them and what models you will need to fulfil your needs.

This is more of a usage for Data Scientists and Machine Learning users who want to use already pre built models from the library, like Decision Trees or Random Forest Algorithms.

You can just import the Built in Models and use them in code.
Sklearn is much more easier to use and is also a popular library for quick to implement ML solutions.

However, Tensorflow is more of a machine learning / deep learning library, where you kind of actually make the entire model by yourself, from scratch using tensors.
From scratch as in, you make the model's architecture and provide its parameters like:

1. How many hidden layers will be there
2. How many neurons will be there, from 1 to 10 to 1000 or even more in each layer.
3. What are the input values and output values, their matrix sizes.
4. What sort of learning rule it will use, the metrics for analysis and evaluating your model.
5. Neural Networks evaluation, experimentation and then porting them for other usages.

You basically design your own neural network, which is either a basic one or a deep neural network depending on how complex it is.

Tensorflow gives you full control of your ML model as well, for proper visualization and seeing the architecture of your model as well (this is what I love about it).

On a nutshell, sklearn is more popular for data scientists while Tensorflow (along with PyTorch) is more popular among ML engineers or deep learning engineers or ML experts.

Edit. PyTorch is becoming more common due to its ability to run the training over the GPU(just any GPU with CUDA support or AMD GPU) without any need for manual configuration or installations of CuDNNs or CUDA toolkit. The PyTorch installation already comes with all these things. If you are interested in Deep Learning, PyTorch is a very good platform to go for.